# oracle license - find how many days left for license to expire

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to find the type of license and days left for the license to expire for remote oracle databases.The dict views I researched on oracle 11G R2 were v$license , dba_feature_usage_statistics and PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION, however none fits the purpose. I cannot find the number of days for the license to expire for "each" product component. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not stored in your database.  You do not have to register each database with Oracle, and I'm not even sure if there is a method to do that.  There is Oracle Configuration Manager, but that is meant to gather information to be used on My Oracle Support, and I'm not sure if that includes license information either.

The best I can find is www.oracle.com/store/contracts.  It lists contract dates.  But they aren't necessarily tied to a specific database.  Most of your databases probably aren't "licensed" anyway - you can download and run any version of Oracle for free, for development and prototyping purposes.  And Express Edition can be used for almost anything.  And there's nothing preventing you from using licensed features.  There's a lot of trust involved.

But I've only bought the cheap personal edition.  I'd be interested to hear from someone else who has spent significantly more money on a different version.

Comment: hi jonearles, nice to know that oracle does not restricts its editions use. I come from DB2 LUW and that comes with specified trial days, so was thinking on those lines.